# Alfresco content search inside current folders or it's childs

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts, alfresco-enterprise, alfresco-maven

I want to customize Alfresco share in such a way, where I can search contents from specific folder or it's child folders only.

If I am searching document inside XYZ folder of particular site the it should search documents within that XYZ folder or it's child folders only.

For now I can think about customize Alfresco default search, customize site search dashlet or customize Alfresco Advanced search, but not getting any lead for this.

How can I achieve this functionality and What will be the easiest way to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to specify a folder context for search results (see: https://alfresco.atlassian.net/browse/MNT-16749).  You may be able to post filter the search results at the display point (filtering out all results that do not have the folder in the path).

Comment: Also - here's an older solution that may work for you: https://hub.alfresco.com/t5/ecm-archive/advanced-search-search-in-location/m-p/19435/thread-id/10440